# Google BigQuery does not drop the temporary tables created inside a transaction when the transaction aborts

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, transactions, temp-tables

All temporary tables that get created inside a transaction seem to remain in place after the transaction rollback.
However, I would expect that all changes made inside the transaction would be abandoned including the temp tables creates. Is this a bug or the intended behavior?

I tried running the following

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `t4` (`i` INT64 );
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; -- Something happens and trasaction aborts 

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `t4` (`i` INT64 ); -- this fails with tables already exists. 
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

I expect the first create to be abandoned and the second create to be successful.

Comment: Not sure why, and I don't get this error, but consider `CREATE OR REPLACE` instead of just `CREATE` in your DDL.

Comment: @rtenha Thank you for the suggestion. I still get the error when I run the above script, and I tried the Google Cloud console and the ODBC driver